# Metamask not allowing any transaction by code

Tags: metamask

I am building an application using ethereum smart contracts. I am using Metamask Chrome extension to run my application on Chrome. But I am facing a little issue. When I try to make any transaction by code Metamask say's that the account balance of sender is insufficient despite of the fact that sender's account has ethers in it. On the other hand when I try to make a transaction through my Metamask account there is not error and transactions are being made successfully.

Here is the screenshot of Metamask

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

And here is the screenshot for the sender's account having ether

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your metamask UI, there's 0 ether in the address 0x64F66

Since it's test net, just use https://faucet.metamask.io/ to add ether to your test net address.